# Parallel Matlab - Create distributed arrays

Tags: parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I have two long (1,000,000+ entries) vectors `I` and `J` like so

```
N = 1000000;
M = 1000;
I = ceil(M*rand(1,N));
J = ceil(M*rand(1,N));
```

and they contain a bunch of indices which I use to select elements from a small vector

```
R = randn(1,M)
```

like so

```
R1 = R(I);
R2 = R(J);
```

The resulting vectors `R1` and `R2` have length `N` of course. Now I want to do some heavy-duty processing on these vectors, for instance compute

```
Q = exp(-(R1-R2).^2);
```

How could I parallelize this code for efficient multicore processing? I suppose that R1 and R2 should be cast in distributed (or rather codistributed) form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an NVIDIA GPU compatible with CUDA and the Parallel Computing Toolbox installed, you can try this:

```
N = 1000000;
M = 1000;
I = ceil(M*gpuArray.rand(1,N));
J = ceil(M*gpuArray.rand(1,N));
R = gpuArray.randn(1,M);
R1 = R(I);
R2 = R(J);
Q = exp(-(R1-R2).^2);
```

The code will be parallelized under-the-hood and executed on the GPU on thousands of threads. On my machine (CPU Xeon E5-2665, GPU Tesla K20) I get more than 10x speedup between CPU (serial) and GPU.